# objective c how to accessing applicationDidFinishLaunching variables from outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I know that may be a naive question but its a problem for me. now i have declared objects in applicationDidFinishLaunching. how to use this objects outside applicationDidFinishLaunching
how to use those objects in an button action function for example

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application
AKanji *test2=[[AKanji alloc] init];
 ........
   }



 - (IBAction)kButton:(id)sender {
     //iwant to access test 2 here

     }
```

Comment: What is your history of knowledge for Object Oriented code and instance variables?

Comment: I am new to them. sorry I have searched the web bot didn't found any answer

Comment: You should read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1, and through to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2 to understand this part

Comment: thanks a lot I will read it :)

Comment: Your instance or object should assigned Global declaration.

Comment: @user1478 don't encourage the use of global state as it's bad practice & not a good design approach. Indeed, if this is proposed to be done in the AppDelegate class (like some of the answers assume) that is also wrong - the question doesn't look like it though as it's using notifications so hopefully the app delegate isn't being abused here.

Comment: read the apple docs or http://www.raywenderlich.com can be a good starting point to learn, try my answer for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `AppDelegate.h`, import the file which you would like create instance

#import AKanji.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder
@property(nonatomic, strong) AKanji *test2;
@end
```

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
               // Insert code here to initialize your application
               _test2 =[[AKanji alloc] init];
               ........
  }
```

in ViewController.m

```
#import AppDelegate.h

- (IBAction)kButton:(id)sender {
    //iwant to access test 2 here
    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    // Now you can access using delegate.test2

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should understand what is an Object Oriented Programming Language, and its proper use.

Now coming to your question part. Its not possible at all to access the *local* variables in other methods. It gets created and gets destroyed once the scope / lifetime is over.  (in your case it is a local variable)

To achieve that, you need to use an ivar / property, assign the value in that method and then you can access it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to move your Kanji *test2 outside of applicationDidFinishLaunching braces. You should should still be able to alloc/init it in there if that's where you want to do it, and you will also see it in kButton.

Comment: thanks a lot i got It I will move it to be as property

Answer (score -1):

The AppDelegate class has an init as any other class.
Therefore it can have @properties.
So on init you can do any initialization of elements so then can be used all over the class.

Comment: got it so i have to declare them as properties to access them any where is that right? thanks a lot

Comment: hup @AlaaAhmadM.Zakaria in general properties are variables accessible at class level. If you put them inside the .m (only inside the class), if you put them on .h from outside